# SEO module to change tag title for different listing page

Tags: title, seo

I need to have different tag titles for each category of my website.
I've tried all in one SEO but it looks like i cannot change it individually.

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you mean the `<title></title>` in `<head>` section different for each category ?

Comment: Yes, I've got 5 pages with different list of contents. I need them with different keyword.

Comment: Please please be *the* Syd Barrett... xD

Comment: @TheDeadMedic: yeah, the madcap is still laughting!

Comment: do you still using allinone seo pack ? Also provide how you currently displaying `<title>`

Comment: Yes, I went into Pages and I can do it there individually.

Comment: So you got solution to this problem ?

Comment: It looks like. I'm testing and see if I can do what i need with this plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you mind using the "description" field for tags as the SEO title? If so:

```
add_filter( 'single_term_title', 'wpse_60464_title_from_description' );
function wpse_60464_title_from_description( $title )
{
    if ( ( $obj = get_queried_object() ) && ! empty( $obj->description ) )
        $title = $obj->description;
    return $title
}
```

Comment: I found the solution in all in one SEO.

Comment: Could you please explain how you resolved your issue using all in one SEO?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Joost de Valk's Wordpress SEO plugin, which will do the job.